# what is line-height in css?

Tags: html, css

So there can be only two possibilities.

1) if line-height is height between two lines then what will be the line-height for one line ??

2) if line height is height of line then if i make line-height to 0 so nothing should be visible right ?
but as you can see in example after line-height 0 the content is visible .

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
p {
    line-height: 0;
}


</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>
First Line First Line First Line First Line First Line<br>
Second Line Second Line Second Line<br>
Third Line Third Line <br>
</p>


</body>
</html>
```

so which one is correct ?

Comment: [line-height - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/line-height)

Comment: It’s the height of a line as far as layout is concerned, but it doesn’t stop the text from being rendered.

Comment: @Rajesh thanks but which one is correct 1st one or 2nd one ?

Comment: https://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/line-height/ the best one to describe

Comment: @Mahi I have added an answer and tried to make it explanatory. Please drop a comment if you have a query

Comment: @Mahi If you got the helpful answer, remember to [accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct answer is the second (partially!!): `line-height` property is the height of each text line, but **if the content of line overflow it, this will be no hidden because, by default, the html elements does not hide the content that overflow its container**.

If you add `overflow: hidden` you will have evidence of this.

```css
.sampleText {
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 12px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<p class="sampleText">This is a Sample Text!!</p>
```

As you can see, `line-height` refer to the height of line and the rest of text was hidden when we add `overflow:hidden`. If the `overflow: hidden` is missing, the text will have the default property of html for all elements: `overflow:visible`.

If `line-height` property value is greater than `font-size`, the text will be aligned middle vertically, as you can see in the next example.

```css
.sampleText {
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 40px;
  background-color: sandybrown;
}
```

```html
<p class="sampleText">This is a Sample Text!!</p>
```

Comment: you mean height between lines ?

Comment: No, is the height of each line. Try adding overflow: hidden and you will see.

Comment: Also try a realy big line height to see its effect. The Text will also be vertical aligned in the middle if the lineheight is higher then the font-height.

so if you have text which is 5px and a lineheight of 15px you gonna have 5px above and below every line which is free. So you could think this is the height between lines aswell

Comment: @Mahi I'm sorry, the second it's correct partially!!

Answer (score 2):

As per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/line-height)

> On block level elements, the line-height property specifies the minimum height of line boxes within the element.
>
> On non-replaced inline elements, line-height specifies the height that is used to calculate line box height.

What it means is, if you set it to a block element line `<div>`, it defines its height of line box. What `Line-box` means is the height of a line a block element will have.

For others(*inline*) element like `<span>`, it will define the line height of container it is rendered in (*Check last div in below snippet*).

```css
div{
  border: 1px solid grey;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px 4px;
}

span{
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 50px;
  overflow: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}

.test1{
  line-height: 30px;
}
.test2{
  line-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test1"><span> Hello </span></div>
<div class="test2"><span> World </span></div>

<div>
  <span class="test1"> Test 2</span>
</div>

<div>
  <span class="test2"> Test 3</span>
</div>

<div>
  <span class="test1"> Test 4</span>
  <span class="test2"> Test 5 to test wrap</span>
  <span>this it to justify</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'line-height' property specifies how 'tall' a line should be. it does not increase/decrease the font size, it only says how much space the text will take up vertically. If it's too low, in a paragraph the words would go over each other. If it's too high, the words would be far apart. More on that here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_line-height.asp

Answer (score 0):

> On block level elements, the line-height property specifies the
>   minimum height of line boxes within the element.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height

Searching in the web I find that the line-height is the height of the line, but it will always render text.

As I find in a Spanish web, the standard value of line-height is `1.0` t0 `2.0` (without unity like px, pt...)

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd one is true. Line-height means the height of one line.

I sometimes use line-height property to vertically center the text in any kind of element.

As you see in the samples below; in first p, line-height is bigger than font-size and the text is vertically centered in line.

In second p, line-height is smaller than the font-size and the text overflowed the line.

In the last p, line-height is smaller than the font-size and p's overflow property is set to hidden, so the text is overflowed and partly visible.

```css
p#p1 {
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  font-size:12px;
  line-height:36px;
}

p#p2 {
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  font-size:36px;
  line-height:12px;
}

p#p3 {
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  font-size:36px;
  line-height:12px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<p id="p1">
  Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum
  </p>

<p id="p2">
  Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum
  </p>

<p id="p3">
  Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum
  </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [CSS line-height property](https://kolosek.com/css-line-height/) defines the **amount of space used for lines**, most commonly in the text. It is often confused with line spacing (leading) used in Photoshop and similar software.

Leading is a term that describes the distance between the baselines in the text. In the case of defining leading, space is always added below the text. But, when working with line-height property, **space is always added equally above and below the text**.

Line height can be defined with **px, em, percentages and unitless values**. One of the examples of the usage of line-height is here:

```
div {
  Font-family: ‘Lato’, sans-serif;
  Font-size: 14px;
  Line-height: 2 // equals to 28px
}
```

Here we see if you set the line-height **without a unit**, the result is the line-height value **multiplied** by the element’s font-size.